# Find quadratic equation given 3 points in R

Tags: r

Is there any package in R that finds the quadratic equation given 3 points or do I have to do it manually?

I have a list that contains the values for x and a list that contains the values for y.

```
x = tail(mylist_x,3)
y = tail(mylist_y,3)
```

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you! Is there any example?

Comment: i'm not aware of the **R package** but can tell you the mathematical  way to solve it and the limitation of that approach where it fails. should i tell you that in the answer section?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use linear regression:

```
x <- 1:3
y <- 0.5 * x^2 + 3 * x - 2

coef(lm(y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)))
#(Intercept) poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)1 poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)2 
#       -2.0                     3.0                     0.5
```

Or as pointed out in the comments:

```
solve(cbind(1, x, x^2), y)
#        x      
#-2.0  3.0  0.5
```

Note that `lm` can handle some edge cases (e.g., three non-unique points), whereas `solve` can't.

Comment: I stand corrected, plus one. Out of interest, does it work with the points not being distinct or in a straight line?

Comment: @Roland, I only have values for x and y. I don't have any equation. I want to find it.

Comment: @Bathsheba Test it. If you set beta2 to zero, regression gives you a zero.

Comment: `x` and `y` here **are** the values for x and y. You only have to do the line `coef(...)`

Comment: @zinon You said you have points, i.e., x and y values. I just created some for demonstration.

Comment: @Roland Thank you very much! That is the solution to my problem!